# Cannot access (async) callback function Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the esri promise with Jest & Enzyme

```
import { esriPromise } from 'react-arcgis';
componentWillMount(){
            this.setState({name: 'JAKE'});
            this.addTileLayer();

          };

addTileLayer(ext, url) {
      this.setState({name: 'Amber'});
        let promise = esriPromise(['esri/layers/TileLayer']).then(([TileLayer]) => {
            this.setState({name: 'THISONE'});
            let tileLayer = new TileLayer();

            this.setState({
                layers: [...this.state.layers, tileLayer]
            })
        }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
           this.setState({prmoise: promise})
    };
```

In my test,

```
test('Promise states check', async () => {
    const map = shallow(<Map />)
    await map.instance().componentWillMount();
    console.log(map.state());
 });
```

But it always prints, promise: Promise { < pending > } } Seems like it's not going inside the esriPromise function. (I have also tried done() which was unsuccessful as well)

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May be instead of shallow you would have to use mount here which will run the life cycle hooks for you

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the esriPromise in the addTileLayer function

Comment: thanks for your reply @mattphilips I tried but no luck... I think the promise is in pending stage when jest calls it. How could I wait until it resolves the promise?